# prosilica_gige_sdk

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**entering rosmake prosilica_gige_sdk results in the following error, what does it mean?**

/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/prosilica_driver$ rosmake prosilica_gige_sdk

[ rosmake ] rosmake 
starting...

[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: 
['prosilica_gige_sdk']

[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/mike/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120606-114142

[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['prosilica_gige_sdk'] to:

['prosilica_gige_sdk']

[rosmake-0] Starting >>> prosilica_gige_sdk [ make ]

[ rosmake ] All 12 linesrosilica_gige_sdk: 0.0 sec ]                                                                                     
                       [ 1 Active 0/1 Complete ]

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  make wipe

  make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/prosilica_driver/prosilica_gige_sdk' <br>  cd build && make clean <br>  /bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to build <br>  make[1]: [clean] Error 2 (ignored) <br>  rm -rf build <br>  rm -rf include lib bin <br>  rm -f *~ installed <br>  make[1]: Leaving directory` /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/prosilica_driver/prosilica_gige_sdk'

  touch wiped

  touch: cannot touch `wiped': Permission denied

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package prosilica_gige_sdk written to:

[ rosmake ]    /home/mike/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120606-114142/prosilica_gige_sdk/build_output.log

[rosmake-0] Finished <<< prosilica_gige_sdk [FAIL] [ 0.08 seconds ]

[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package prosilica_gige_sdk.

[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.

[ rosmake ] 
Results:

[ rosmake ] Built 1 packages with 1 
failures.

[ rosmake ] Summary output to 
directory

[ rosmake ] /home/mike/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120606-114142

**the content of that file**

" ============================================================================

" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v143)

"   /home/mike/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120606-114142

"   Sorted by      name

"   Sort sequence: [/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,.c$,\.cpp$,~=*$,*,\.o$,.obj$,<br>\.info$,.swp$,\.bak$,~$

"   Quick Help: :help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:exec

" ============================================================================

../

prosilica_gige_sdk/

buildfailures-with-context.txt

buildfailures.txt

profile.txt

.swp

~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35812/prosilica_gige_sdk/) by [mikeS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2457/mikes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2012-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to build files installed by the binary Debian package.

That is:

1. not necessary, and
2. not permitted (because you lack write access to those directories).

Why are you doing it?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1